# How can I install an android app that I created with another android app that I created (Android Studio)?

Tags: android

My goal is to have a menu where the user can select a new android app and then install it in the same phone. Both apps (the main app and the new app) are created by me. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download an apk and then launch package manager to install it. This will ask users permission and user can deny to install it.

Something like this can be used -

```
    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        final long id = manager.enqueue(request);
    
    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setDataAndType(uri,
                        manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(id));
                startActivity(install);
    
                unregisterReceiver(this);
                finish();
            }
        };
registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

Hope this helps!